# Adminjs implementation issue "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backend, adminjs

I'm new in node express js. Just trying to writting the backend code using express js. Now I want to add adminjs in my project. As I'm new in this section, I've followed the official documentation of adminjs express plugin https://docs.adminjs.co/installation/plugins/express

But I'm facing issue while running app.js

```
import AdminJSExpress from '@adminjs/express'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1339:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1434:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v21.5.0
```

I have gone through the chatGPT. it suggest me to add `"type": module` in `package.json`. but I don't want to change it to module. I also don't want to use `typescript`

I just want to add admin panel in my existing project which is `frogbase` using `express.js` and `postgresql`

If you want you can also checkout the github repository https://github.com/frogbase/frogbase

Comment: Version 7 of AdminJS no longer support CJS projects. You could try a workaround using dynamic [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) but it may just be easier to migrate your project to use ES Modules. It's the way things in Node are going I'm afraid.

Comment: @jQueeny can you tell me how can I convert my project to ES Module please. I have already share the github url.

Comment: You would need to go through each `require` statement and refactor to use  `import` if you wanted to migrate to ES Modules. Most npm packages have docs for using ES modules and Common JS. I can give you an example of how to use dynamic `import()` in your current CommonJS pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use [@adminjs/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adminjs/express)
 so not 100% sure this will work for you but looking at its ES export from npm and the [AdminJS Express simple example](https://docs.adminjs.co/installation/plugins/express#simple) you can try this:

```js
const express = require('express');

Promise.all([
    import('adminjs'),
    import('@adminjs/express'),
]).then(([{default: AdminJS}, {default: AdminJSExpress}]) => {
    const PORT = 3000
    const app = express()

    const admin = new AdminJS({})

    const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.buildRouter(admin)
    app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter)

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`AdminJS started on http://localhost:${PORT}${admin.options.rootPath}`)
    })
});
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer since you copied it, instead of `{default: plugin}` it should be `{default: AdminJSExpress}`.

Comment: You're welcome. This is a bit of a hack and there are many plugins from looking at the AdminJS docs that you may want to use down the line (all ES modules) so you could run into issues again with CommonJS/ES compatibility. All of the projects I work on now use ES Modules so it may be a good idea to think about migrating.

Comment: I'll try. @jQueeny can you please check this problem, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774726/adminjs-with-postgresql-implementation-error-while-showing-table-data