# Adminjs with postgresql implementation error while showing table data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backend, adminjs

I'm new in using [adminjs](https://adminjs.co/). I have created a node express js project to handle my backend. I've used postgresql as database. So that I use `@adminjs/sql` admin authentication is working properly. But I', facing some issues while try to show the tables of the postgresql. As I'm a beginner I have followed the official documentation https://docs.adminjs.co/installation/adapters/sql
Here is my `app.js` file:

```
const express = require("express");
require("express-async-errors");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const routes = require("./routes");
const compression = require("compression");
const unknownEndpoint = require("./middleware/unKnownEndpoint");
const { handleError } = require("./helpers/error");

const app = express();

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(compression());
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

// CORS handling
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

app.use(`/api`, routes);

Promise.all([
    import('adminjs'),
    import('@adminjs/express'),
    import('connect-pg-simple'),
    import('express-session'),
    import('@adminjs/sql'),
]).then(async ([
    { default: AdminJS },
    { default: AdminJSExpress },
    { default: Connect },
    { default: session },
    { default: { Adapter, Resource, Database } },
]) => {
    const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.POSTGRES_USER}:${process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${process.env.POSTGRES_HOST}:${process.env.POSTGRES_PORT}/${process.env.POSTGRES_DB}`;

    AdminJS.registerAdapter({ Database, Resource })

    const db = await new Adapter('postgresql', {
        connectionString: connectionString,
        database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    }).init();

    const DEFAULT_ADMIN = { email: 'admin@algoramming.com', password: '@Admin123', name: 'FrogBase Admin' }

    const authenticate = async (email, password) => {
        if (email === DEFAULT_ADMIN.email && password === DEFAULT_ADMIN.password) return Promise.resolve(DEFAULT_ADMIN)
        return null
    }

    const adminJS = new AdminJS({
        version: { admin: true, app: process.env.PROJECT_VERSION },
        rootPath: "/admin",
        databases: [db],
    });
    const ConnectSession = Connect(session)
    const sessionStore = new ConnectSession({
        conObject: {
            connectionString: connectionString,
            /*
            SSL is not supported in development
            */
            ssl:
                process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
                    ? { rejectUnauthorized: false }
                    : false,
        },
        tableName: 'adminjs',
        createTableIfMissing: true,
    });
    const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter(
        adminJS,
        {
            authenticate,
            cookieName: process.env.COOKIE_NAME,
            cookiePassword: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
        },
        null,
        {
            store: sessionStore,
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
            cookie: {
                httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            },
            name: process.env.COOKIE_NAME,
        }
    )
    app.use(adminJS.options.rootPath, adminRouter)

    app.use('*', unknownEndpoint);
    app.use(handleError);
});

module.exports = app;
```

And the error I'm facing is

```
file:///Users/sabikrahat/Files/Algoramming/frogbase/frogbase/node_modules/adminjs/lib/adminjs.js:101
      throw new Error('Adapter has to have both Database and Resource');
            ^

Error: Adapter has to have both Database and Resource
    at AdminJS.registerAdapter (file:///Users/sabikrahat/Files/Algoramming/frogbase/frogbase/node_modules/adminjs/lib/adminjs.js:101:13)
    at /Users/sabikrahat/Files/Algoramming/frogbase/frogbase/app.js:54:13
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```js
{ default: { Adapter, Resource, Database } }
```

To this:

```js
{ default: Adapter, Resource, Database }
```

At the minute you're assigning an object containing 3 modules to `default` when the adminjs/sql docs look like they are exporting `Adapter` as the `default`.